# Is there a proper way to create an html src path?

Tags: c#, html, path, imagesource, path-separator

I know that the proper way to handle file/directory paths is to use `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar`, but does this apply to html source paths?

Or, is it that the backslash is the required path separator for html? I've always done it using the backslash (i.e. `<img src="images\birthdaysurprise.jpg" />`), but now I'm wondering if I've been doing it improperly this entire time?

Comment: URI's should always use forward slash "/" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme

Comment: @JTorres: Well, right off of the bat I've already been doing it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "letter of the law" is that forward slash ('/') is the way to do it. Per [RFC 2396, *Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax*](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt), §3, "URI Syntactic Components":

```
The URI syntax does not require that the scheme-specific-part have
any general structure or set of semantics which is common among all
URI.  However, a subset of URI do share a common syntax for
representing hierarchical relationships within the namespace.  This
"generic URI" syntax consists of a sequence of four main components:

   <scheme>://<authority><path>?<query>

each of which, except <scheme>, may be absent from a particular URI.
For example, some URI schemes do not allow an <authority> component,
and others do not use a <query> component.

   absoluteURI   = scheme ":" ( hier_part | opaque_part )

URI that are hierarchical in nature use the slash "/" character for
separating hierarchical components.  For some file systems, a "/"
character (used to denote the hierarchical structure of a URI) is the
delimiter used to construct a file name hierarchy, and thus the URI
path will look similar to a file pathname.  This does NOT imply that
the resource is a file or that the URI maps to an actual filesystem
pathname.

   hier_part     = ( net_path | abs_path ) [ "?" query ]

   net_path      = "//" authority [ abs_path ]

   abs_path      = "/"  path_segments

URI that do not make use of the slash "/" character for separating
hierarchical components are considered opaque by the generic URI
parser.

   opaque_part   = uric_no_slash *uric

   uric_no_slash = unreserved | escaped | ";" | "?" | ":" | "@" |
                   "&" | "=" | "+" | "$" | ","

We use the term <path> to refer to both the <abs_path> and
<opaque_part> constructs, since they are mutually exclusive for any
given URI and can be parsed as a single component.
```

Your URI needs a minimal number of forward slashes to separate the *scheme* from the *authority*. The remainder of the URI (the *path* and *query* components) really have  meaning only within the context of the pertinent *scheme* and *authority*. However, a couple of things to consider:

- One, URI *paths* are **not** filesystem paths (unless the URI scheme is `file` (`file://...`). URI paths are simply identifiers with meaning to *authority* that **may** (or may not) map to particular filesystem entries.
- Two, opaque URI paths (ones not using `'/'` as the path separator, can't be processed very well by generic tools. Further, it's not necessarily apparent that the path in question is opaque: meaning application of generic tools to your opaque URI may result in unexpected behaviors.

Answer (score 2):

While I don't know the exact letter of the law, use the forward slash for all path separators.  Even Windows can use a forward slash as a separator in its APIs.

Using a backslash may work under a windows platform but:

- It looks weird
- Will die and gag if you move to a *nix based system.
- May end up breaking some code that assume the forward slash
- `\` starts an escape sequence in many instances, so `\n` could translate in an unexpected way.

Comment: Not to mention "\" is typically denotes the beginning of an escape sequence on many platforms.